# Fast way to find the sum of LCM of the given range of numbers?

Tags: algorithms, spoj, least-common-multiple

I want to find the sum of LCM of a given range of integers. For example:

**Input:** $5$
**Output:**

\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^5 \mathrm{LCM}(i,5) & = 
\mathrm{LCM}(1,5) +\mathrm{LCM}(2,5) +\mathrm{LCM}(3,5) + \mathrm{LCM}(4,5) + \mathrm{LCM}(5,5) \\
 & = 5 + 10 + 15 + 20  + 5 \\
 & = 55
\end{align}

The method I use right now is to find the $\mathrm{GCD}(a,b)$ using Euclidean method and them compute $\mathrm{LCM}(a,n)$ as $\frac{|ab|}{\mathrm{GCD}(a,b)}$.  The problem with this method is that it's very slow for inputs in the range of $1 < n < 10^5$.

I got some details of using Euler's totient function to do the same but I don't understand it completely.The one property which I understood is a $\phi(p) = p-1$ where $p$ is prime and I couldn't understand how to use this to improve the speed of my problem.The current algorithm which I use runs at $O(n^2)$ and I need to do better than that.

Comment: If you have a fixed number in each LCM, like $5$, you can just prime factorize it once and check how many times those prime factors divide the other numbers to get the GCD.

Comment: To be clear: You want to know if there is a robust function such that $f(n)=\sum_i^n LCM(i,n)$; here I use "robust" in an informal sense.... like $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\sum_{i=0}^n i$.

Comment: @Squirtle Yeah exactly.If not is there a better way to do than what I have used.

Comment: @Nishant Yeah that's right but it will give only a marginal improvement in terms of performance.

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:project-euler].  Which problem number is this?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Probably [this one](http://projecteuler.net/problem=448).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, OK.  I ask because without the context of modular arithmetic (which is in the original problem), it can happen that OP is asking for an elegant/efficient solution to a problem that might not have one.  I.e., the possible efficiency might arise from the part of the problem that OP *isn't* telling us about.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor No my problem is to just find the sum of lcm of a given range 1 to N and it has nothing to do with the project euler problem I tagged it by mistake.

Comment: @user1613360 OK, though I'm not sure how you'd tag it by mistake… did you accidentally type project-eu and got an autocomplete or something? At any rate, the reason I bring it up is that the project Euler question that's very similar to this doesn't stop with computing this sum, but does something else with it.  The extra computation that it does may be the key to simplifying this.

Comment: I probably shouldn't, but: group the numbers by $\gcd(a,n)$.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know the euklidian algorithm for gcd runs in $O(\log n)$, this would give you a total complexity of $O(n \log n)$, wich is a lot faster than your $O(n^2)$ algorithm.
I programmed it in python and for $n=10^5$ it only needed a second.

About the Eulers totient: calculating $\phi(n)$ is as fast as factorizing $n$. 
if $n=\prod_{i \in I}p_i^{v_i}$ for $p_i$ prime numbers, then $\phi(n) = \prod_{i \in I}(p_i^{v_i-1}  (p_i -1))$.
It counts the numbers $k$ from $1$ to $n$ with $gcd(k,n)=1$ , but i am not sure if it can be used for a very efficient algorithm (faster than $O(n \log n)$ ).

Comment: Just chiming to agree that performance here would seem to only matter if you're doing this many times in an inner loop.  Using Perl with a module that does lcm in C, $n=10^7$ via naively summing lcm(i,n) is only 0.2 seconds.  Very straightforward LCM via simple GCD.

Comment: @supinf Yeah thats right but the problem is I am doing that for 10000 test cases which reduces my performance drastically.

Answer (score 0):

You may speed it up a bit by making only 1 multiplication:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\text{lcm}(i,n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i n}{\gcd(i,n)}=n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{\gcd(i,n)}$$

Since $i$ is divisible by $\gcd(i,n)$ that can be computed using only integer arithmetic.
This has $O(n*log(n))$ complexity but is in constant factor faster than naive solution (2nd formula).

Comment: This is actually a tougher operation since computing $\gcd(i,n)$ is just as tough as computing $lcm(i,n)$ but now you are also including a inversion and multiplication by $i$.

Comment: @Squirtle But how do you compute LCM without computing GCD and dividing both $i$ and $n$ by GCD?

Comment: Are you asking me how the computer computes lcm and gcd? Or? Because I don't know how the computer does it, but if the computer needs gcd to do lcm then your method above can't better because allegedly that's how the computer would have to do it anyway. Alternatively, if the computer can independently compute gcd or lcm without the other then your method is actually slower. Either way, your method isn't better.

Comment: @Squirtle If you are using Euklidian algorithm then you are forced to use 2nd formula which uses $n$ multiplications, but you can use 3rd formula to use only 1 multiplication. However if you are calculating LCM using prime factorization, then this is not applicable at all.

Comment: @Squirtle Actually prime factorization is slower than this, because you need to factor $n$ numbers and factorization algorithms have bigger complexity than O(n), however this uses O(n log n), as pointed by supinf.